# Does bcache support use of an LVM logical volume as a cache device?

Tags: crash, bcache

I've got a 64GB SSD and a 3TB hard drive in my system running Ubuntu 14.04. The SSD has a small root partition with rest of the device allocated to an LVM physical volume. From that LVM physical volume I have two logical volumes allocated, one for /usr and one for /root. (/home is on the 3TB hard drive.)

Since I had about 25GB of the SSD currently unused, I thought it would be interesting to try using it as a bcache cache device with /home as backing device.

I created a new logical volume using the remaining space on the LVM physical volume on the SSD. That left things looking like this:

```
# pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda2  VG4  lvm2 a--  53.57g    0 
  /dev/sdb2  VG6  lvm2 a--   2.69t    0 
# lvs
  LV      VG   Attr      LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  VG4-usr VG4  -wi-ao--- 19.31g                                           
  VG4-var VG4  -wi-ao---  9.31g                                           
  bcache  VG4  -wi-ao--- 24.95g                                           
  home    VG6  -wi-ao---  2.69t
```

I then did:

```
# make-bcache -C /dev/mapper/VG4-bcache
```

The system immediately locked up completely. (So the above is a reconstruction, I don't have the actual command I executed any more.)

Did I do something stupid without realising it? Is this a supported configuration? I'm wondering if it's worth reporting this as a bug or not. Nothing appears to have been permanently harmed by the crash.

Comment: Weird...  I suppose you mean by "SSD has a small root partition " --> "SSD has a small **b**oot partition"?  Hold on! You used an LVM as a bcache device???  I never tried that.  I always use PVs...  I need to take a system backup before trying that out!

Comment: /dev/sda1 is the primary, non-LVM partition on the SSD; it's a 2GB ext4 partition which is mounted as /, but it does contain /boot. Yes, I was trying to use an LVM logical volume as the bcache caching device. I couldn't find anything saying it didn't work, and since other "weird" stuff like using a USB drive as cache device is supported I thought I'd try it. If this isn't supported then fair enough, but it would be nice if it didn't just blow up (hence wondering if I should report it as a bug). I could try using a PV, assuming it's possible to shrink the existing SSD PV to make room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **definitely think you should file a bug**.  I've never even thought about using a LV as bcache, only PV.  And maybe (just maybe) you're the first one who's ever tried...  And it's probably not handled...

Do you want me to proceed with a SysBck and try this myself? (Not today any more: too tired!)

Do you have a [system backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)??? (you're user type 4)

Comment: I do have backups, thanks! (Although only of my user data and stuff like /etc; I don't have an image of the OS installation I could just restore and *bang* it's back, I'd have to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch had the worst happened.) It would obviously be nice if you tried this, but only if it will satisfy your own curiosity - I'd hate to put you out, and it sounds like a big faff (unless you have a virtual machine to try it on?!). I'll leave it a day or two before I file a bug so if you do try it there's extra information available for the report.

Comment: Nope, no VM: ***I've got backupS,*** so I'll try this out on my laptop tomorrow-morning if there is no excrement on the ventilator when I walk in...  ;-)

Comment: Busybusy. It'll have to wait for the W.E.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, since I've gone ahead and [reported the bug on the bcache mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.bcache.devel/2821).

Comment: I need to consider urgently, to which user type I belong … =)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. I accidently did my setup backwards. I set my lvm as the caching device and my ramdrive as the backing device. But yet, to answer your question it does work.

But I should mention that lvm2 has a caching feature, you might as well opt to use that (which is what I did) and then use bcache if you want to cache the lvm to ram

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was due to the device already being actively used in bcache, as confirmed by `bcache-super-show`.

```
$ make-bcache -B /dev/ssd/cache
Can't open dev /dev/ssd/cache: Device or resource busy

$ make-bcache -C /dev/ssd/cache
Can't open dev /dev/ssd/cache: Device or resource busy

$ pvs
  PV                      VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/mapper/md100-crypt hdd    lvm2 a--    3.64t 186.30g
  /dev/mapper/md101-crypt ssd    lvm2 a--  119.17g  32.23g
  /dev/md0                system lvm2 a--   13.81g   4.50g

$ lvs
  LV    VG     Attr      LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  data  hdd    -wi-ao---  3.46t
  cache ssd    -wi-ao--- 29.75g
  data  ssd    -wi-ao--- 57.20g
  root  system -wi-ao—  9.31g
```

Seems to fail on the following

```
open("/dev/ssd/cache", O_RDWR|O_EXCL) = -1 EBUSY (Device or resource busy)
```

Before that failure, the following seems to succeed;

```
open("/dev/ssd/cache", O_RDONLY) = 4
ioctl(4, BLKSSZGET, 512) = 0
close(4)             = 0
```

This leads me to believe that `O_EXCL` is responsible for the `EBUSY`, indicating that perhaps another process is holding a lock on the device, however I can confirm that `/dev/ssd/cache` is not mounted, open or in use (as seen in lsof or fuser), and that rebooting does not resolve the problem.

Attempting to remove it from device-mapper also yields no progress;

```
$ dmsetup remove ssd-cache
device-mapper: remove ioctl on ssd-cache failed: Device or resource busy
```

So after running `lsblk` I can see the following;

```
sdb                        8:16   0 119.2G  0 disk
└─sdb1                     8:17   0 119.2G  0 part
  └─md101                  9:101  0 119.2G  0 raid1
    └─md101-crypt (dm-3) 252:3    0 119.2G  0 crypt
      ├─ssd-data (dm-4)  252:4    0  57.2G  0 lvm   /mnt/ssd/data
      └─ssd-cache (dm-5) 252:5    0  29.8G  0 lvm
        └─bcache0        251:0    0  29.8G  0 disk
```

As you can see, bcache0 is a child of the device in question, and a quick check confirms this;

```
$ bcache-super-show /dev/ssd/cache
sb.magic        ok
sb.first_sector     8 [match]
sb.csum         9F5D50331A2A10B9 [match]
sb.version      1 [backing device]
dev.label       (empty)
dev.uuid        8ba675a3-d9e4-4d47-8403-655c226f578f
dev.sectors_per_block   1
dev.sectors_per_bucket  1024
dev.data.first_sector   16
dev.data.cache_mode 0 [writethrough]
dev.data.cache_state    0 [detached]
cset.uuid       c006c316-d396-40cf-bde8-8bd4d0a017e8
```

Therefore, the root problem in my case was that the device itself was already part of bcache, and `make-bcache` failed to detect this.

Hopefully this will be useful to someone else in future.